# force:inputField lookup doesnt work for custom Object

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

I am using force:inputField for Custom object lookup field

```
<aura:attribute name="portPair" type="Port_Pair__c" 
default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Port_Pair__c' }"/>

<force:inputField aura:id="portOfLoading"  class="slds-input" 
value="{!v.portPair.Terminal_of_Loading__c}"/>
```

It gives an Error, But the same force:inputField works for standard Object  Contact.OwnerID

[image]

Comment: Did you check that you didn't misspell the name of the field and that you have field level permission to that field?

Comment: Can you also try to mock some default value for that field in 

default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Port_Pair__c',  'Terminal_of_Loading__c':'default mock value'}"/>